# Is it possible to block port 80 on a K8s ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I'm using the GKE Ingress controller. The ingress is configured to terminate TLS, the underlying service is listening on port 80.

I don't need to serve my frontend externally on port 80 and would prefer that the LB created by the controller keep that port closed. I can't figure out if that's even possible, or what to change in the ingress resource definition.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: foo-ingress
  namespace: foo
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - foo.example.com
    secretName: foo-example-com-cert
  rules:
  - host: foo.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: foo-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [disable HTTP on your cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress-xlb#disabling_http) and then set [HTTP-to-HTTPS redirect](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#https_redirect) by creating an additional load balancer on the same IP address.

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1beta1
kind: FrontendConfig
metadata:
  name: ssl-redirect
spec:
  redirectToHttps:
    enabled: true

# add below to ingress
# metadata:
#   annotations:
#     networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: ssl-redirect
```

**Note** - While disabling you'll need to recreate your cluster for this change to be applied on the load balancer.

You can also refer to this [Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/290) link for more information.

Comment: I think that github link is discussing a different problem. BUT it mentions an annotation that looks relevant `kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"`. In fact, that's mentioned in the [official GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress-xlb#disabling_http) under "Disabling HTTP". Wouldn't that be sufficient?

Comment: Yes it should be sufficient enough.

Comment: I tried it. It didn't do what I expected. When set, the LB's port 80 is still open but you get a 503 response for every request. I don't know if that's the intended behaviour.